# MongoDB get json file

Tags: mongodb

I am new in MongoDB and currently using MongoDB v3.2 with MeanJS boilerplate v0.4.2. The CRUD operation works as expected. But it seems that i am unable to locate the file which store the data to decompile to readable json format. Which is the correct file of data storage and how to convert into readable json format? I suspect is one of the wt file but i not sure which one is it and how to convert to readable json format since most of the tutorial i see is convert from bson to json.

Note: I have convert storage.bson to json and it does not store the data information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB is not strong your data in actual JSON files. You can however export your data to JSON. You can use the following command to export a single collection to JSON:

```
mongoexport --db test --collection storage --out storage.json
```

Do not forget to replace all the required variables where `test` is the name of your database, `storage` is the name of your required collection and `storage.json` will be the name of your file. The exported file will be saved in your pwd of your terminal.